Can a positive and negative voltage regulator be connected in parallel on a diode bridge and capacitor?
Can a positive and negative voltage regulator be connected in parallel on a diode bridge and capacitor? If so, how would this be done? Example: L7924 & L7812.
I have a 12A transformer with two center tap windings, one is used for primary voltage, that is switched between 25V & 50V. The other winding is an Aux negative voltage used to drive the output voltage to zero volts when adjusted so.
I also have a need for +12V for other circuitry on the board, hence the question as stated above.



Can you use the schematic tool and edit your question to draw a schemtatic?

your description seems a little unclear, a drawing of what you have and a clear desciption of what you want to add would be most helpful

Your last schematic seems to show the -24V output connected to GND.  You will need a -28 V (or so) supply as input to the L7924 - the L7924 volt regulator can't create a negative supply itself - it can just regulate an existing negative source.

The input to the L7924 is coming off BR5 in the upper schematic. I think you are looking at the ground symbol's tag, its not on the input.

You have a GND symbol to the left of C22, with a wire connecting that point to the L7924 GND and C24 and R53 and to a -24V symbol.  The bottom left diodes of BR2 and BR5 are in parallel but opposite polarity, effectively holdinig the top lead of the transformer winding at or near GND - I don't think that will work.  It is not clear where the output of the L7924 is, if -24V is its input.

I have bread-boarded up the circuit, and it appears to work just fine with a load or without. However there is one exception. When I tie the negative regulator ground together with the positive regulator ground the negative regulator's output gains 2 volts more (-14v).  Not clear on what going on here. Any thoughts here?
